# issue when inserting data to database

Tags: php, mysql

My code doesn't insert any records to mysql. What is wrong? I am really confused.
I have designed a form and I want to read data from text box and send to the database.

```
<?php
if(isset($_post["tfname"]))
    {
        $id=$_post["tfid"];
        $name=$_post["tfname"];
        $family=$_post["tffamily"];
        $mark=$_post["tfmark"];
        $tel=$_post["tftell"];

$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$link)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("university",$link);
$insert="insert into student (sid,sname,sfamily,smark,stel) values ($id,'$name','$family',$mark,$tel)";

mysql_query($insert,$link);
    }
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: PHP variables are case sensitive; `$_post` won't work since the correct variable is `$_POST` (if you have proper error reporting options set, this should come up in a notice). Also, you should check whether the query executes correctly and display/log the `mysql_error()` if it doesn't. By the way, are you aware that even if your script works, there's a gaping SQL injection hole in it with which any potential attacker could plunder your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better to put quotation mark for id, mark and tel after values in your query. Also as @Another Code said, you must use $_POST instead of $_post in your code. Try this and tell me the result:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["tfname"])) {
   $id=$_POST["tfid"];
   $name=$_POST["tfname"];
   $family=$_POST["tffamily"];
   $mark=$_POST["tfmark"];
   $tel=$_POST["tftell"];

   $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   if (!$link) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   } else {
      mysql_select_db("university",$link);
      $insert="insert into student 
               (sid,sname,sfamily,smark,stel) values 
               ('$id','$name','$family','$mark','$tel')";
      mysql_query($insert,$link) or die (mysql_error());
      mysql_close($link);
   }
} else {
   die('tfname did not send');
}
?>
```

Use `mysql_query($insert,$link) or die (mysql_error());` to fetch the error message.

Comment: @sami : WOULD YOU PROVIDE THE ERROR THAT YOU GET?? writing it didn't work is NOT AN ANSWER...

Comment: `die` should usually be avoided for error handling, see my comment on @yuvrajm's answer.

Comment: i am beginner and excuse me for crazy mistake.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you've provided it could almost be anything - to do some tests... have you echo'd something to confirm you are even getting the tfname in POST? Does it select the database fine? Do the fields $id, $mark, and $tel need single quotes around them as well? We need to know more about where the code is not working to provide more help but that snippet appears as though it should be running, in the interim, please use some echo's to narrow down your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the generated sql query in the sql query browser. Get the query by "echo $insert" statement.

Answer (score -1):

change the $insert to:

```
$insert="insert into student (sid,sname,sfamily,smark,stel) values ($id,'".$name."','".$family."','".$mark."','".$tel."')";
```

further set `ini_set('display_errors',1)` so that php displays the error messages as required.

Lastly, whenever doing a mysql query, try to use `or die(mysql_error())` in the query so that if somethings wrong with mysql or syntax, we are aware.

```
$q = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `die` should not be used for error handling, since it shuts the entire script down. This can easily cause bugs and weird output, and in live environments it's a bad idea to directly show script errors to the user at all. It's important to just write proper error-handling routines.

Comment: I gave this example considering the app is working as a test run and once the error is rectified, the die feature can removed...

Comment: That's perfectly fine, but it's good to make a note about that so people are aware that it's meant for debugging only. Also, a script always needs proper (database) error handling; queries that work right now might decide to stop working in the future.

Comment: do you think there is a better alternative to `die()` which will not stop the script? how abt using `if(!$query){ //report the error and display something if required }`